# Jquery if else statement not working in Google Chrome or safari

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, if-statement, css-selectors

Trying to get a overlay to pop up when I select certain icons.

Problems:
1.) This works great in FF but not anywhere else. It works in chrome sometimes when I am inspecting the element. 
2.) There has to be a shorter way to write this code...?

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var $quickview = $(".quickview");


$('.quickview').click(function() {
    var $t = $(this).parents("a");

    if($t.is(":nth-child(1)")){
        var css={}
        $("#overlay1").css("display","block");
        console.log("1")
        }
    else if($t.is(":nth-child(2)")){
        var css={}
        $("#overlay2").css("display","block");
        console.log("2")
        }
    else if($t.is(":nth-child(3)")){
        var css={}
        $("#overlay3").css("display","block");

        }
    else if($t.is(":nth-child(4)")){
        var css={}
        $("#overlay4").css("display","block");
        }
    else if($t.is(":nth-child(5)")){
        var css={}
        $("#overlay5").css("display","block");
        }
    else if($t.is(":nth-child(6)")){
        var css={}
        $("#overlay6").css("display","block");
        }
    else if($t.is(":nth-child(7)")){
        var css={}
        $("#overlay7").css("display","block");
        }
    else if($t.is(":nth-child(8)")){
        var css={}
        $("#overlay8").css("display","block");
        }
    else if($t.is(":nth-child(9)")){
        var css={}
        $("#overlay9").css("display","block");
        }
    else if($t.is(":nth-child(10)")){
        var css={}
        $("#overlay10").css("display","block");
        }

$('.exit, .overlay').click(function() {


    if($t.is(":nth-child(1)")){
        var css={}
        $("#overlay1").css("display","none");
        }
    else if($t.is(":nth-child(2)")){
        var css={}
        $("#overlay2").css("display","none");
        }
    else if($t.is(":nth-child(3)")){
        var css={}
        $("#overlay3").css("display","none");
        }
    else if($t.is(":nth-child(4)")){
        var css={}
        $("#overlay4").css("display","none");
        }
    else if($t.is(":nth-child(5)")){
        var css={}
        $("#overlay5").css("display","none");
        }
    else if($t.is(":nth-child(6)")){
        var css={}
        $("#overlay6").css("display","none");
        }
    else if($t.is(":nth-child(7)")){
        var css={}
        $("#overlay7").css("display","none");
        }
    else if($t.is(":nth-child(8)")){
        var css={}
        $("#overlay8").css("display","none");
        }
    else if($t.is(":nth-child(9)")){
        var css={}
        $("#overlay9").css("display","none");
        }
    else if($t.is(":nth-child(10)")){
        var css={}
        $("#overlay10").css("display","none");
        }
    });
});

});
```

Please Help!
Thanks!

Comment: Jquery doesn't have if/else statements. JavaScript does. Try using a select/case statement instead.

Comment: To shorten yout code. Replace the body of the `click` handler with: `var $t = $(this).closest("a");var index = $t.parent().children("a").index($t)+1;$("#overlay"+index).show();`. To fix your issue: Please clarify your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried something like this

```
$('.quickview').click(function() {
    var i = ( $(this).parents("a").index() + 1 );
     $("#overlay"+ i).css("display","block");
     console.log(i);

});
```

Comment: `i+1` to meet the exact criteria. [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) is zero-based, whilst `nth-child` is one-based. Also, `.css("display","block")` is equivalent to `.show()`.

Comment: +1 for the `i+1`.  i will edit to reflect. however, i will leave the css to reflect `display` `block`.  he could be working with a span and having it to some type of effect

Comment: Thanks All!! Really helped! I would have been stuck on this for 5 more days.